# Rigorous Definition On composition of Multivariable Functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, manifolds

Suppose you have $f(x_1,.....x_n)\colon R^n \to R$ and $g_1,...g_n\colon  R^m \to R$.

Then $f(g_1,....g_n)$=$f\circ(g_1,...g_n)$ :$R^m \to R$, right?

Any clear definition on composition of multivariable functions? Also I had problem while studying Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*.  The Chain Rule  theorem states

$$D(f\circ g)(a)=Df(g(a)) \circ Dg(a).$$ 
Now suppose $f,g\colon R^n\to R$ and $H(x,y)\colon R^2 \to R$. Then $$H\circ (f,g)=H(f,g)\tag{1}$$

So $$D(H(f,g))=DH \circ (f,g)=DH \circ D(f,g)$$ Now does the last one equal $D(f,g)=(Df,Dg)$?
 So $(1)$ becomes $DH \circ (Df,Dg)$?? Is that true and why? I'm trying to understand  the proofs of the derivatives of multiplication and addition on multivariable functions.

Comment: What the heck is that $1$ doing there?

Comment: @GitGud It should have been a \tag. Fixed.

Comment: @BrianO Damn, I was getting angry. I thought it was another notational abuse by analysts.

Comment: $$D(f\circ g)(a)=Df(g(a)) \circ Dg(a).$$, what's the physical intuition behind the rule.